# Delete only Directories (not files) older than x days in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, gnu-findutils

I am trying to list the directories (but not files) older than x days. I used below command to do it. But it is listing directories and files. Could anyone help me in resolving it? Thanks.

```
find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -ctime +10 -exec ls {} \;
```

Comment: it is listing directories and files because you are saying `ls {}` to the results. Instead, do use `ls -d {}` to list the directory itself.

Comment: GNU `find` has an `-ls` action that behaves like `ls -dils` for what `find` finds.

Comment: If you just want the output like `ls -d` would show it, you can remove the action, which defaults to `-print` and is the same as `-exec ls -d {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find /path/to/base/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

First to test if all is alright :

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -ctime +10 -exec ls -d {} \;
```

When all is ok :

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

Explanations :

```
ls -d :  list directories themselves, not their contents
rm -f :  ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```